# Starting Google Maps activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start Google Maps activity like this:

```
    Intent start = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:"+58.0+","+58.0));
    startActivity(start);
```

But I am getting activity not found exception.

Do I have to declare Google Maps Activity?
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This mean Google Maps is not installed (nor anything else that thinks it can handle this link). You need to catch the exception and prompt the user to download from the market.